# jQuery Scrollbars not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll

I am having a problem whereby the scrollbars on my jquery dialog are not showing up even though the content is very much larger than the dialog window.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Here is the dialog initialisation code:

```
$("#divFoo").dialog({
autoOpen: false,
modal: true,
height: 500,
width: 500,
closeText: '',
position: 'center',
draggable: true,
open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
});
```

Here is how i am opening it:

```
$("#divFoo").dialog("open");
```

Here is the CSS from the stylesheet:

```
#divFoo
{
    display:none;
}
```

Here is the HTML div:

```
<div id="divFoo">
    <table id="tableFoo" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>                
            <td id="tdPP01"><img id="imgPP01" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP02"><img id="imgPP02" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP03"><img id="imgPP03" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP04"><img id="imgPP04" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP05"><img id="imgPP05" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP06"><img id="imgPP06" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP07"><img id="imgPP07" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP08"><img id="imgPP08" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP09"><img id="imgPP09" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP10"><img id="imgPP10" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP11"><img id="imgPP11" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP12"><img id="imgPP12" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP13"><img id="imgPP13" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP14"><img id="imgPP14" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="tdPP15"><img id="imgPP15" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP16"><img id="imgPP16" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP17"><img id="imgPP17" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP18"><img id="imgPP18" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP19"><img id="imgPP19" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP20"><img id="imgPP20" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP21"><img id="imgPP21" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP22"><img id="imgPP22" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP23"><img id="imgPP23" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP24"><img id="imgPP24" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP25"><img id="imgPP25" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP26"><img id="imgPP26" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP27"><img id="imgPP27" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP28"><img id="imgPP28" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="tdPP29"><img id="imgPP29" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP30"><img id="imgPP30" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP31"><img id="imgPP31" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP32"><img id="imgPP32" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP33"><img id="imgPP33" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP34"><img id="imgPP34" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP35"><img id="imgPP35" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP36"><img id="imgPP36" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP37"><img id="imgPP37" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP38"><img id="imgPP38" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP39"><img id="imgPP39" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP40"><img id="imgPP40" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP41"><img id="imgPP41" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP42"><img id="imgPP42" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="tdPP43"><img id="imgPP43" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP44"><img id="imgPP44" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP45"><img id="imgPP45" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP46"><img id="imgPP46" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP47"><img id="imgPP47" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP48"><img id="imgPP48" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP49"><img id="imgPP49" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP50"><img id="imgPP50" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP51"><img id="imgPP51" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP52"><img id="imgPP52" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP53"><img id="imgPP53" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP54"><img id="imgPP54" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP55"><img id="imgPP55" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP56"><img id="imgPP56" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="tdPP57"><img id="imgPP57" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP58"><img id="imgPP58" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP59"><img id="imgPP59" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP60"><img id="imgPP60" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP61"><img id="imgPP61" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP62"><img id="imgPP62" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP63"><img id="imgPP63" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP64"><img id="imgPP64" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP65"><img id="imgPP65" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP66"><img id="imgPP66" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP67"><img id="imgPP67" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP68"><img id="imgPP68" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP69"><img id="imgPP69" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP70"><img id="imgPP70" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="tdPP71"><img id="imgPP71" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP72"><img id="imgPP72" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP73"><img id="imgPP73" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP74"><img id="imgPP74" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP75"><img id="imgPP75" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP76"><img id="imgPP76" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP77"><img id="imgPP77" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP78"><img id="imgPP78" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td id="tdPP79"><img id="imgPP79" src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the style of #divFoo to have `overflow:false` and also add `resizable: 'false'` to dialog initialization.

Comment: i am actually trying to set the scrollbars 'to' show, not to hide them. but your answer has indirectly led me to the solution - to set the overflow:scroll in css which worked. thanks!  i think...

Comment: I think they *want* the scrollbars, which would be `overflow` set to `auto`.

Comment: For more info about `overflow` see [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

Comment: Whoops, yeah I meant to say `overflow: auto` hah. Good going figuring it out.